# How good is Mootools backward compatibility?

Tags: mootools, backwards-compatibility

A coworker of mine has had issue with Mootools being backward compatible and I was wondering if anyone else had noticed this?  He said that his main problem was when trying to using the drag and drop functionality offered in an older version. I never really looked into it myself, but when I mentioned it when asking the same question for JQuery others did not seem to have the same problem.

So Stackoverflow have you ever noticed an issue with Mootools backward compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mootools 1.2 is not fully backward compatible with Mootools 1.11.  You can find some information about what's changed in the [Mootools Wiki](http://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wikis/conversion-from-1-11-to-1-2) and I've also found [Siafoo's article about upgrading to 1.2](http://www.siafoo.net/article/62) very useful in the past.

Upgrading older scripts is generally a matter of finding deprecated method references and replacing them with new ones; easy, just a minor pain.